# Identifying a line with an equivalence class

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, equivalence-relations

I'm really struggling to come up with an equivalence relation that I feel should be simple: 
If we describe a line $L$ by a direction vector $\textbf{v}$ and a point $\textbf{x}$, can we introduce an equivalence relation on pairs $(\textbf{x}, \textbf{v})$ so that a given line $L$ can be identified to an equivalence class. (i.e I'm looking to find an equivalence relation $(\textbf{x}, \textbf{v})$ ~ $(\textbf{y}, \textbf{u})$ only if they represent exactly the same line.

Comment: I also might need to use the equivalence relation to introduce an atlas later? Not sure if that's relevant to how the equivalence class is constructed.

Comment: So the relation is that $L_1 \sim LL_2$ if and only if they are the same line?

Comment: What kind of equivalence are you trying to describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}) \sim (\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{u)}$ iff $\mathbf{v} = \alpha \mathbf{u}$ for $\alpha \ne 0$ and $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} + \beta \mathbf{v}$ for some $\beta$? (**Edit**: the original answer said erroneously said $\beta \ne 0$) I believe this satisfies your needs.

Comment: I thought about that but worried I was over-complicating it? It definitely works but I'm not sure if there's an easier way to define it. Thank you though!

Comment: I'm also not sure how I'd use that equivalence relaiton to introduce an atlas and calculate the changes of coordinates.

Comment: Doesn’t this definition exclude $(\mathbf x,\alpha\mathbf u)$?